# laravel model attributes aliases - best practice

Tags: laravel, model, pointer-aliasing

I use an old database on a legacy system that should be migrated to a new laravel system on the long term. The naming of the database columns is not clean an convenient, so I'd like to add attribute aliases to make the migration more easy in the future.

E.g. the table has columns like `PascalCase` and `OtherLanguageThanEnglish` those names should be `pascal_case` and `english_column_name` in the migrated table.

In the meantime - to use both systems without changing everything - the model should have some "translation matrix" like

```
protected $cleanAttributes = [
    'PascalCase'                => 'pascal_case',
    'OtherLanguageThanEnglish'  => 'english_column_name',
];
```

so I can access them with `$model->pascalCase` and `$model->englishColumnName`.

I know there is the magic `getPascalCaseAttribute()` method, but this seems a bit repetitive, especially if the table has lots of columns. And how can I set those new attributes?

**Edit**

Just learned of the existence of the methods `getAttributes()` and `setAttributes()` so i extracted a trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait HasAttributeAliases
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        if (!isset($this->map)) $map = [];
        else $map = $this->map;

        if (in_array($key, $map)) {
            return $this->attributes[array_search($key, $map)];
        } elseif (in_array(Str::snake($key), $map)) {
            return $this->attributes[array_search(Str::snake($key), $map)];
        } else {
            if (in_array($key, array_keys($this->attributes))) return $this->attributes[$key];
            elseif (in_array($key, array_keys($this->relations))) return $this->relations[$key];
            else return null;
        }
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (!isset($this->map)) $map = [];
        else $map = $this->map;

        if (in_array($key, $map)) {
            $this->attributes[array_search($key, $map)] = $value;
        } elseif (in_array(Str::snake($key), $map)) {
            $this->attributes[array_search(Str::snake($key), $map)] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

That can be used in the Model in combination with an array
`$protected $map = ['old_key' => 'new_key' ...]`

Is this practicable? Any drawbacks for "overriding" standard Model functionallity?

Comment: `getPascalCaseAttribute` is the old syntax, check out https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators for the new syntax, which has both a `get` and `set` method.